# How do I extend Ecto.Repo to broadcast changes to pubsub?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to get my app's Repo to broadcast inserts on a phoenix channel, but I'm not sure about the right way to extend `Ecto.Repo`. I've tried this, but I'm getting compilation, and it doesn't like the right strategy either. What should I be doing here?

```
defmodule Mars.Repo do
  require Logger

  use Ecto.Repo,
    otp_app: :mars,
    adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres

  def insert(x, opts) do
    with {:ok, result} <- Ecto.Repo.insert(x, opts) do
      broadcast(result)
      {:ok, result}
    else
      e -> e
    end
  end

end
```

Current working solution:

```
  def insert_cast(x, opts \\ []), do: action_cast(&Repo.insert/2, x, opts)
  def transaction_cast(x, opts \\ []), do: action_cast(&Repo.transaction/2, x, opts)

  defp action_cast(action, x, opts \\ []) do
    with {:ok, result} <- action.(x, opts) do
      try do
        broadcast(result)
      rescue
        e ->
          Logger.warn("#{__MODULE__} could not broadcast for #{inspect(x)}")
          {:ok, result}
      end

      {:ok, result}
    else
      e -> e
    end
  end
```

Comment: What error do you get back? What’s “right strategy”?

Comment: In this case, I get errors because insert is already defined above in use Ecto.Repo. I've udpated the post with my current solution that works; it might actually be the best that I can really hope for here. I decided to create new functions to not interfere with the Ecto ones.

Comment: I like your approach. An alternative could be to define those functions in a BroadcasterRepo where it would call your Mars.Repo